# Google Apps Script: How to get the conditional format rules in a sheet, including the values for each rule

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I can't seem to figure out how to get all of the conditional formats in a sheet, and particularly get the values that are set within the conditions.

I have a sheet with a column of quantities. Each quantity has a unique conditional formatting value set, such that if the quantity value in the cell drops below this threshold value (set within the conditional format), then the background of the cell turns red.

This is all working just fine.

The issue is that i need to access the unique threshold values that are set for each of these cells via the conditional formatting.

I have tried many different variations on 
`var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules()`, etc. then looped through these rules only to get strange `Logger.log` results which look like this:

```
com.google.apps.maestro.server.beans.trix.impl.ConditionalFormatRuleApiAdapter@17521c6a
```

Followed exactly and failed with the following documentation as well:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule#getBooleanCondition()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/boolean-condition

Comment: do you have conditional formating on other columns?

Comment: hi, thx for the response, no i don't. just the one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : I got that the line was your log result...

It appears like that because it's an object, it does that too when you try to log a range without the A1Notation(). It just means you aren't using a method that returns an array or a value.

Following the documentation you link, the [getCriteriaValues() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/boolean-condition#getcriteriavalues) should work for what you need. Work for me like this :

```
function findThresholds() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();;
  var formats = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var thresholds = [];
  formats.forEach(function(format, i) {
    var booleanCondition = format.getBooleanCondition();
    if (booleanCondition) {
      var threshold = booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues();
      thresholds.push(threshold[0]) //if you have more than one value per contional format, omit [0]
    }
  });
  return thresholds
```

This pushes them into an array but you can do something with them directly too.

Edit 2 : because it's pertinent to know what row the threshold is on :
For each format you can use the .getRanges() method. Then, on each ranges you'll to .getRow() to know what row this range starts at. And in case that range is more than one row high, you'll want to getValues(), to be able to count each row like by adding the index value of the row to the starting row you got earlier. Finally you can push that value as a key and the threshod value as a value in a dict and you'll be able to call the row to get your threshold value.

```
function findThresholds() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(<sheet name>);
  var formats = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var thresholds = {};
  formats.forEach(function(format) {
    var booleanCondition = format.getBooleanCondition();
    var ranges = format.getRanges();
    if (booleanCondition) {
      var threshold = booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues();
      ranges.forEach(function(range) {
        var rowStart = range.getRow();
        var rows = [];
        var vals = range.getValues(); //if every format only apply to one row, you may omit this part and just use 'rowStart' as 'row'
        for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
          var row = (rowStart+i);
          thresholds[row] = threshold[0]
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return thresholds
}
```

Comment: this works! but i am facing a strange problem where i am seeing the threshold values, but they are out of expected order? it's almost as if perhaps the thresholds are in the order that i created them in originally (i don't think i created them one by one starting at row 1 on the sheet), rather than the order of the spreadsheet (i.e. row 1 conditional threshold value would be the first threshold value in the array, etc).

Comment: yes I do think they are in that order. But, I was checking how to get it if you had cond. formating in more than one column and you can actually get the range for the cond, format, so you could push the row index with the threshold value in a dict or something to then be able to get them by row. Does each row has it's own or do some share theirs?

Comment: each cell in the column has it's own conditional format rule with it's own threshold value. i haven't tested your findThresholds() function yet, but now that i know you can use getRanges(), i'm sure it will work! will give it a try and let you know. thanks so much!